# Set parameter of any Func<>

Tags: c#, reflection, system.reflection

I have an object of any of the func types func<>, Func<,>, func<,,> ... And I'd like to replace one of the input parameters with a constant value.

eg:

```
object SetParameter<T>(object function, int index, T value){
    //I don't know how to code this.
}

Func<int, String, String> function = (a, b) => a.ToString() + b;
object objectFunction = function;
object newFunction = SetParameter<int>(objectFunction, 0, 5);
// Here the new function should be a Func<String, String> which value "(b) => function(5, b)"
```

I already now how to get the type of the resulting function, but that does not really help me in implementing the desired behavior:

```
private Type GetNewFunctionType<T>(object originalFunction, int index, T value)
{
    Type genericType = originalFunction.GetType();

    if (genericType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var types = genericType.GetGenericArguments().ToList();
        types.RemoveAt(index);
        Type genericTypeDefinition = genericType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
        return genericTypeDefinition.MakeGenericType(types.ToArray());
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"{nameof(originalFunction)} must be a generic type");
}
```

Comment: The result of your method will have to be an `object` as well, since you can't declare a method to return the right func with the missing parameter.

Comment: You're probably going to have to use reflection.emit or expressions to generate the code for this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you need to [use expression tree to build the function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/):

```
object SetParameter<T>(object function, int index, T value)
{
    var parameterTypes = function.GetType().GetGenericArguments();

    // Skip where i == index
    var newFuncParameterTypes = parameterTypes.SkipWhile((_, i) => i == index).ToArray();

    // Let's assume function is Fun<,,> to make this example simple :)
    var newFuncType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(newFuncParameterTypes);

    // Now build a new function using expression tree.
    var methodCallParameterTypes = parameterTypes.Reverse().Skip(1).Reverse().ToArray();
    var methodCallParameters = methodCallParameterTypes.Select(
        (t, i) => i == index
            ? (Expression)Expression.Constant(value, typeof(T))
            : Expression.Parameter(t, "b")
        ).ToArray();

    // func.Invoke(5, b)
    var callFunction = Expression.Invoke(
        Expression.Constant(function),
        methodCallParameters);

    // b => func.Invoke(5, b)
    var newFunc = Expression.Lambda(
        newFuncType,
        callFunction,
        methodCallParameters.OfType<ParameterExpression>()
    ).Compile();

    return newFunc;
}
```

To use this:

```
Func<int, string, string> func = (a, b) => a.ToString() + b;

var newFunc = (Func<string, string>)SetParameter<int>(func, 0, 5);

// Output: 5b
Console.WriteLine(newFunc("b"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what the purpose of your conversion is for, but wouldn't it be easier to avoid all the reflection. E.g.:

```
Func<int, string, string> func3 = (a, b) => a.ToString() + b;

Func<string, string> func3withConst = (b) => func3(10, b);
```

Since you are talking about a very limited scope (supporting just `Func<TReturn>`, `Func<T1, TReturn>` and `Func<T1, T2, TReturn>`) doing this through reflection is much more error prone and harder to read.

Comment: I cannot avoid the reflection because I want to create a function which works for any type of func and not just 1 specific case

Comment: Can you show us a use case for it? I have a hard time seeing the benefit of making some convoluted reflection working instead of the simple one-liner I provided. How does the example I provided not work for you?  Please update your question with this info

Comment: Notice that he also wants to specify the index of the parameter to replace, so he wants to support replacing the second parameter as well, which complicates matters. This, though, sounds like something "nice to have", but I think the complexity here outweighs any small benefit it might have.

Comment: I think your best option is to create methods like this `public static Func<T1, TResult> BindSecond<T1, T2, TResult>(this Func<T1, T2, TResult> func, T2 v2) => (T1 v1) => func(v1, v2);`, and then just specify the index using the method name, you can then use it on a func like `func.BindSecond(17)` which will create a func with the second parameter locked to 17.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how do you mean "complicates matters"? What's the problem with `Func<int, int, string> converted = (i1, i3) => threeParamFunc(i1, 100, i3);`? You can put that `100` anywhere you like.

Comment: So now create a method that allows you to specify if you want to replace the first or second parameter.

Comment: I could indeed create methods like Lasse V. Karlsen described but there are a lot of  possible combinations. Also since the input type of my method is still object I'd still have to use reflection to call these function. So it would be nice to have a simpler solution

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen why do you need this extra/separate method for it? The thing is you can do this on one line, a separate method wouldn't save you anything.

Comment: @Lukesta please provide an example of how you want to use this. I don't see any reason right now to want to make this "helper function" to input these "constants" for you.

Comment: I agree with not needing it, but OP doesn't. But yes, I fully agree, simply making up the delegates as you need them without any such method is better.

Comment: @Xerillio It is for a node editor for a procedural generation tool which I'm creating. I want to add func types to it while keeping it as flexible as possible. That's why I need a function which works for every type and not just specific types

Comment: @Lukesta you need to provide a code example and explain/show why a simple solution like the one I suggested isn't working in your scenario. Please update it in your question so everyone can see it without reading through comments.

Comment: @Xerillio your code example does not work for an input of type object

Comment: @Lukesta I can't help you without a code example from you. Why does the "input" need to be an `object`? In your first code snippet, you cast a `Func`: `object objectFunction = function;` is there a need for this?